# Not to use Noreply while sending email via Sendgrid

Tags: email, sendgrid

I have questions regarding using domain name while sending email via sendgrid.

1) Sendgrid recommend that one should not use `"noreply@domain.com"` as their domain. I came to know about it after reading the following documentation:
http://sendgrid.com/blog/why-you-should-not-use-noreplydomain-com-in-your-emails/

Does anyone has any clue which domain names are best handled by Sendgrid? I am thinking to use `"info @ domain.com"` instead of

```
"noreply@domain.com".
```

2) By the way, it's the word `"noreply"` that is creating problem, am I right? I am new to these things and still understanding domain related terms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid will handle your email the same way regardless of the from domain. The recommendation not to use noreply@ is just so the people receiving your email can more easily communicate with you.

SendGrid by default does not provide any mailboxes or inbound mail processing. You can use the [Inbound Parse Webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) to receive emails, but that is more intended for use cases where you need to programmatically deal with the incoming email.

In the case of just being able to receive email responses, it is probably easier to create a mailbox via your hosting company, or to use something like a gmail account and have your host/registrar forward your mail there.